# Default-568h@2x.png is being scaled

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a Default-568h@2x.png image which is 640 x 1136 pixels. It shows improperly on the 4" simulator, it is scaled some when the launch image is displayed. Not by much, but the image has a circle and it clearly shows an oval.

The "Hide during application launch" checkbox doesn't change the stretching. (The status bar style is default and it does not show while the launch image is visible both when the checkbox is checked and not checked.)

I can't show the graphic, the client wouldn't like that, but the circle is a slight oval.

Comment: Are you running the simulator with SDK 6.0? If you run it with 4' and 5.1 you'll get weird scaling of stuff.

Comment: That's exactly correct! Make that an answer and I'll give you a green checkmark. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you are running the 4'' simulator with SDK 6.0. iOS 5.1 does not support 4'' screens, so weird things will happen (stretching, or a double status bar in some cases).

Sadly enough, the simulator will allow you to select both SDK 5.1 and 4'' device.